# MongoDB connection error, after updating cluster in mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

So, I made a new cluster using MongoDB but now when I try running `npm run dev`, I received the following error

```
> server@1.0.0 dev 
> nodemon server.js
 [nodemon] 3.0.1 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon]
 watching path(s): *.* [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
 [nodemon] starting `node server.js` Server started on port 5000
 MongoDB connection error: querySrv ENOTFOUND
_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.5i3wd2d.mongodb.net [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I know a common issue is people not removing <> around the user name and password on their connection string however, i have removed it as
you can see

```
mongodb+srv://Username:Password@galeria.bu8vgar.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I am at a loss for what to do, some assistance in figuring out my mistake or issue would be greatly appreciated. If you need I can provide more code but I have searched and the old connection string has been removed.

Comment: from the URL i think you use MongoDB Atlas, isn't it? If yes, then have you checked the IP whitelist of the project/database? It should include your IP Address